# Is it possible to test for a previously created folder on the hard drive

Tags: python

I'd like to create a folder on the hard-drive for the first time the selected model is exported.

After this, the script will fail, because the folder being created by `os.mkdir` already exists:

```
directoryPath = "//_MODEL_FOLDERS_/"
path = bpy.path.abspath(directoryPath)

# fails if dir exists
os.mkdir(path + obj.name)
```

It should be tested.

So does anyone know of a way to test if a folder already exists before trying to create it?

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with blender..?

Comment: I find it odd that you would make an issue that I did not specifically use the word 'Blender' especially since I did say "to create a folder on the HD for the first time the selected model is exported".

Comment: It sounds to me like you are really asking how to test if a directory exists using python. It doesn't matter whether or not you use the word "Blender",  it could be any script you are writing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pure Python.

Comment: Yeah, I did not realize that right away since I only use Python within the context of Blender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to use `os.path.join()` instead of `+`.

To test you can use `os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, obj.name))`

Comment: Could you explain why you should use os.path.join instead? Also, there's a bracket missing at the end of the last line.

Comment: Using `+` will simply join two strings together while [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.join#os.path.join) will join two paths "intelligently" which is to say it will place the correct platform specific separator between them if not already present.